# I is not a real numeric array of class SINGLE

Tags: matlab, mex, vlfeat

I'm using the computer vision: VLfeat library to compute a HOG descriptor of an image, and after inputing this code:

```
cellSize = 8 ;
hog = vl_hog(im, cellSize, 'verbose') ;
```

I get this error in MATLAB, and when I google it I really can't find any possible explanation:

```
Error using vl_hog
I is not a real numeric array of class SINGLE.
```

After going over the code ([found here](http://www.ug.it.usyd.edu.au/~ygao6590/vlfeat-0.9.15/toolbox/misc/vl_hog.c)) I'm also not sure what the variable `I` is:

Hopefully, I haven't missed something elementary ...

[library source](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/hog.html)

Comment: Problem solved! The 'im' variable had to be converted to a SINGLE class type. So im=single(imread('test.jpg')), instead of just im=imread('test.jpg').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the asker already found out, the `I` refers to the first input argument.
Hence this should solve the problem:

```
hog = vl_hog(single(im), cellSize, 'verbose')
```